# How to combine these 2 sql operations into one

Tags: sql, mysql

I would like to know if it's possible to combine 2 operations (SQL) into a single one.

Starting from the following table (TABLE_A), I want to obtain the (TABLE_A.ID) for a user who has the following (TABLE_A.ID_Rights): (9, 11), which belong to groups (TABLE_A.ID_Groups) while inheriting lower rights according to groups and weight (TABLE_A.Weight).

TABLE_A

[image: table-a.png]

So assuming a user has the following TABLE_A.ID_Rights (9 and 11), the query should return me the following TABLE_A.ID (2, 3, 5).

Here is how I managed to get my result in 2 different operations:

**Step 1** - Retrieve all the groups the user belongs to and the respective weight:

Query1 = `SELECT ID_Groups, Weight FROM TABLE_A WHERE ID_Rights IN (9,11)`

**Step 2** - I loop through all the records returned by Query1 and run a second query:

Query2 = `SELECT ID FROM TABLE_A WHERE ID_Groups = Query1.ID_Groups AND Weight <= Query1.Weight`

The combination of these 2 operations gives me the following ID result: (2,3,5)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do a self-join as the following:

```
select A.ID
from table_name A join table_name B
on A.ID_Groups = B.ID_Groups and
   A.Weight <= B.Weight
where B.ID_Rights in (9, 11)
```

[demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/rJ1KfDfL)